# window.onload() not working with html content generated by proprietary fwk

Tags: javascript, dom, cordova, oracle-adf-mobile

I am using a mobile application development framework ADF Mobile whereby we could develop cross-platform mobile applications.UI layer can be developed with a set of components (AMX) that generate an HTML5 based user interface and whose DOM structure can be debugged with iOS simulator+ Safari browser builtin debugger. Also ADF Mobile internally uses Cordova

I need to have a javascript called when the page completes loading. I tried various approaches like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("just inside the  $(document).ready()");
});

window.onload = function () {
    //handler function
};

/*
$(window).load(function () {
    //handler function
});
$(window).bind('load', function () {
    //handler function
});

window.addEventListener("load", handlerFunction);
*/
```

Everything related to 'load' event fails but 'ready' event is getting fired as expected. Once a handler function is associated to the "load" event, when we inspect the window object of the html using the safari dom debugger, the onload attribute has the handler function we are assigning but the only issue is that it is not getting fired when the page is completely loaded.

Can I get any starters on debugging this issue? Or any pointers in getting workarounds will also do.

I was more interested in knowing how this entire mechanism works.

Comment: When you are using jQuery then why do you want to use the javascript code. use the `$(window).load();`

Comment: I tried that! In my above code snippet you can see it in the commented code

Answer (score 0):

How about this ,

```
$(window).on('unload', function(){
      return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```

Actually some browsers such as Google Chrome might block if you attempt to alert in a window unload.

Replace the alert with a console.log or something else less intrusive to the user and the event will be happily called.

Hope this helps you.....

Comment: Seems you are totally off my question. I am not concerned if it is alert or console.log! The function is just NOT being called when the load event is fired

Answer (score 0):

Try executing window.location.reload() from Javascript debugger console.